# Using a dropdown box to display a corresponding value in Django

Tags: django

I am building a Django website and I want to have a page where there is a dropdown box (which is made from a variable in one of my models) and the selection from that dropdown box alters the display down below.

For example: 
I have a model that contains the variables Name & Value
I want to have in a dropdown box all the values for Name, and for the corresponding Value to be displayed when a Name is selected.

Using views.py I can send the values of Name to create the dropdown box. But I don't know how to display the corresponding value when the user selects a Name.

This seems like it probably has a very simple answer, but I am struggling to find an example for this on SO or Django tutorials. (Likely because I don't know the correct terminology to use).

Could someone offer some direction please?

My current **views.py** looks like:

```
def index(request):
    phylogenies = Phylogenies.objects.order_by('names')
    return render(request, 'phylogeny/index.html', context)
```

Which links to this part of relevent html:

**index.html**

```
<form action="PageObjects" method="post">
  <select >
    <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
    {% for p in phylogenies %}
        <option value='{{p.id}}'>{{ p.names }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

Comment: please add actual code template, views.py etc to get a better answer and help you..

Comment: i know that it is better practice to show a worked example showing the error - but I don't have an error. I just don't know how to proceed. Will add my views.py

Comment: edit your question => [edit] <= and add your code...

Comment: do you need get the value of the option selected in your view "PageObjects"  when submit the form?

Comment: Yea I think so. I want to use the value they select in the dropdown box to display something below. e.g. they select p.id and I want to display the corresponding p.value later in the html.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of option selected first you need define a name on your dropdown(template):

```
<form action="PageObjects" method="post">
  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for p in phylogenies %}
        <option value='{{p.id}}'>{{ p.names }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

now, on your views.py to get the value some thing like this:

```
def PageObjects(request):
  myOption = request.POST.get("mySelect") 
  ...
   ...
```

in this case you can get the value(id) by default Django create this value is autoincrement integer number.

good luck..!!

Comment: Cool - thanks for your fast help. A follow up question - this looks like it adds a second view to my view file - correct? How can I access two different views in one template?

Comment: in this case i assume that you need make a submit your form and to get this value submit is on another views...if you need get a result based on selection of dropdown maybe you need use Ajax, jquery...for refresh the contect based on your selection..

Comment: that sounds more like what I need to do. Do you have any pointers for that?

Comment: this is a tutorial for crud ajax with django, please check..: https://www.techiediaries.com/python-django-ajax/